# Schema hasn't been registered

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i'm trying to create ref's in mongoose between models but i have problem with registering model.

My models looks like this

**userModel.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const userModel = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      require: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      require: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      require: true,
    },
    role: {
      type: Number,
      require: true,
      default: 2,
    },
    isPremium: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    beats: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Beat',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

const User = mongoose.model('User', userModel);

export default User;
```

**beatModel.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const beatModel = mongoose.Schema({
  producer: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
  },
  cover: {
    type: String,
  },
  tags: [String],
  plays: {
    type: Number,
  },
});

const Beat = mongoose.model('Beat', beatModel);

export default Beat;
```

Everytime when trying to fetch data by

```
beatModel.findById(id).populate('producer', 'name');
```

i getting only error that
`Schema hasn't been registered for model "User"`

I think that i registered properly my models and i don't know why i still can't link them.

Comment: 2 schema looks ok. The problem is somewhere else in your code. Perhaps you require these schemas after the route code.

Comment: I second what Dang says, you need to require the `user` model file so that it registers itself.